# No matching default constructor for static unique_ptr

Tags: c++, constructor, c++20, unique-ptr

I'm trying to use my custom functions for unique_ptr deletion. But the compiler gives me errors. Somehow I suspect that this is because my deleter is not a class type. But I swear it worked before with functions, I used to plug in C-functions just fine. What is the real deal?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:12),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Ausing+cTYPE+%3D+struct+%7B%0A++++int+a%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avoid+delete_wrapper(cTYPE*+ptr)%0A%7B%0A++++return+free(ptr)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AcTYPE*+new_wrapper()%0A%7B%0A++++return+static_cast%3CcTYPE*%3E(malloc(sizeof(cTYPE)))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++auto+foo+%3D+%5B%5D()+%7B%0A++++++++using+tmp_storage_type+%3D+std::unique_ptr%3CcTYPE,+decltype(delete_wrapper)%3E%3B%0A++++++++static+tmp_storage_type+obj%3B%0A++++++++obj+%3D+tmp_storage_type%7B+new_wrapper(),+delete_wrapper+%7D%3B%0A++++%7D%3B%0A%0A++++foo()%3B++++%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.66057441253264,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Os%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:43.35736354273945,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:56.64263645726055,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.33942558746736,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

using cTYPE = struct {
    int a;
};

void delete_wrapper(cTYPE* ptr)
{
    return free(ptr);
}

cTYPE* new_wrapper()
{
    return static_cast<cTYPE*>(malloc(sizeof(cTYPE)));
}

int main()
{
    auto foo = []() {
        using tmp_storage_type = std::unique_ptr<cTYPE, decltype(delete_wrapper)>;
        static tmp_storage_type obj;
        obj = tmp_storage_type{ new_wrapper(), delete_wrapper };
    };

    foo();    
}
```

Errors (amongst others, clang gives better errors here):

```
<source>:23:33: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::unique_ptr<cTYPE, void (cTYPE *)>' requested here
        static tmp_storage_type obj;
                                ^
<source>:24:15: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'tmp_storage_type' (aka 'unique_ptr<cTYPE, void (cTYPE *)>')
        obj = tmp_storage_type{ new_wrapper(), delete_wrapper };
```

Comment: It is *much* better to use a stateless function object as a deleter https://godbolt.org/z/KW1zfsGWb.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I read that section but then skipped ".. and Deleter is not a pointer type." lol. But why can't it be a pointer type? I don't get it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use a function type as template argument for the `Deleter` template parameter of `std::unique_ptr`. Use a function pointer instead:

```
using tmp_storage_type = std::unique_ptr<cTYPE, decltype(&delete_wrapper)>;
```

Because this would come with the potential pitfall that the value-initialized state of the deleter would be a null pointer, which causes undefined behavior when accidentally called, the default constructor of `std::unique_ptr` is however removed if a pointer type is used and therefore

```
static tmp_storage_type obj;
```

without initializing with a deleter will still not work.

---

It would be better to use a simple function object:

```
struct FreeDeleter {
    void operator()(void* p) const noexcept { std::free(p); }
};

using tmp_storage_type = std::unique_ptr<cTYPE, FreeDeleter>;
```

It also works for all types of pointers allocated with `malloc` and can be used with a default-constructed `std::unique_ptr`.

---

Also beware that using `malloc`/`free` this way only works because `cTYPE` and all of its subobjects happen to be of *implicit-lifetime type*. If that wasn't the case using `malloc` instead of `new` would result in undefined behavior sooner or later.

---

Also beware that `malloc` and `free` are not guaranteed to be imported into the global namespace scope with the includes you are using. First of all because these functions are declared in `<cstdlib>` which you don't include and secondly because even including that they may be declared only in `std::`. So you should qualify them with `std::`.

---

Also, writing `using cTYPE = struct {` is really just a weird way of writing `struct cTYPE {`, except that the former comes with additional restrictions with regards to what the class can contain and how linkage is applied to it.

Comment: I would also mention why `static tmp_storage_type obj;` is erroneous.

Comment: @Enlico I am probably missing something obvious, but why is that wrong?

Comment: I think point 1 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr).

Comment: @Enlico You are right. I didn't remember that the default cosntructor is not available with pointer type deleters. I fixed the answer.

Comment: @user17732522 I didn't know that. Why is that?

Comment: @glades For the reason I mentioned. It was deemed too unsafe. For example you could call `.reset` on a default-constructed `std::unique_ptr` and then the null pointer deleter would be called in the destructor. See [LWG issue 673](https://lwg.github.io/issues/lwg-defects.html#673).

Answer (score 2):

To add up to the other answer, another problem is represented by the line `static tmp_storage_type obj;`.

That line is erroneous not because of `static`, but just because the default constructor is not available, as per the explanation of overload #1 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr). Indeed `std::is_default_constructible<decltype(delete_wrapper)>::value` is `false`, hence `unique_ptr<>::unique_ptr()` is SFINAEd out.